# Fire event when changing route with vue-router before DOM changes?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-events

I'm quite new to Vue, hopefully this won't be a very stupid question :)

The `beforeDestroy` gets fired **after** the DOM structure changes.

I've tried using `beforeUpdate` and `updated` events, but none seems to fire before the DOM changes.

Reproduction online: https://jsfiddle.net/p2c3b10t/18/ (check the console)

Comment: Not a stupid question at all. I was really liking Vue, but I hate that `beforeDestroy` and `destroyed` do not work the way you would expect. From what I read and have been told, the parent has to initiate `beforeDestroy` of a component. So the `beforeDestroy` is not a part of the regular lifecycle. Very stupid, as this works perfectly in React with the use of `componentWillUnmount()`. Thanks for your question as it received an excellent solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with routing with [**Vue Router**](https://router.vuejs.org/), instead of relying on the [**lifecycle hooks**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), use [**navigation guards**](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html). These guards hook into the route navigation process and can be either [**global**](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards), [**per-route**](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard), or [**in-component**](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards).

In this particular case, we are looking for the `beforeRouteLeave` in-component guard.

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  // called when the route that renders this component is about to
  // be navigated away from.
  // has access to `this` component instance.
}
```

In this guard, we can access `to` and `from`, and call `next`.

```
export type NavigationGuard = (
  to: Route,
  from: Route,
  next: (to?: RawLocation | false | ((vm: Vue) => any) | void) => void
) => any
```

- `to` is the target Route being navigated to.
- `from` is the current
  Route being navigated away from.
- `next` is the function that must be called to resolve the hook

**After performing the logic inside this guard, one must call `next()` to resolve the hook.**

---

### [Revised JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4s06vo3y/)

Comment: Awesome answer! Very well explained! Thanks for that @Ricky!

Comment: Thanks! I am happy to help you @Alvaro .

Comment: Hey Ricky, I opened a similar issue. My problem is I can not rely on external routes to fire my event. See the full question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52593490/1081396