# Fire event when changing route before DOM changes and outside the route itself?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-events

I opened [a similar topic a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52541403/1081396), where I was suggested to use `beforeRouteLeave` within the route component definition.

However, I'm creating a Vue component and I won't have control over how developers wants to define their route components. Therefore, I need a way to fire an event within my own component and don't rely on external route components.

When changing from one route to another, the `beforeDestroy` gets fired **after** the DOM structure changes.

I've tried using `beforeUpdate` and `updated` events on my component definition, but none seems to fire before the DOM changes.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyComponent from '../myComponent/' // <-- Need to fire the event here 
import router from './router'

Vue.use(MyComponent)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Sorry for asking, but what is it that you need to accomplish? Because i dont understand. If you build a component why not add a event handler which can be assigned, so the end developer can assign a `beforeRouteLeave` event to the component, and you can write the code for this even already, then you only need to check if the event handler is assigned.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't define a `beforeRouteLeave` inside of your `MyComponent`?

Comment: `beforeRouteLeave` is a [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards). It seems they can only be used within route components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Vue instance lifecycle, the hook `beforeDestroy` gets called once the DOM has changed.

You are most likely looking for a `beforeUnmount` hook, which would be in-between `mounted` and `beforeDestroy`, but that is not available:

[image: lifecycle vue]

However, you could take advantage of [**JavaScript hooks**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks). There is a JavaScript hook called `leave`, where you can access the DOM before it changes.

```
leave: function (el, done) {
  // ...
  done()
},
```

For this to work, you would need to wrap your element in a [***`<transition>`***](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components) wrapper component.

ie.

```
<transition
  :css="false"
  @leave="leave"
>
  <div>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</transition>
```

...

```
methods: {
  leave(el, done) {
    // access to DOM element
    done()
  }
}
```